# Command line interface In JAVA

Tags: interface, command, command-line-interface, command-prompt, remote-access

Actually I want create Interface with java in which I can write Command and Directly got output on the same Interface.

With this interface, I want to fire command to remote machine on the basis of that get some data on the same interface. Remote machine could be windows or linux.

I have also gone through some API on that but not get satisfied answer. 
I want that interface to be attached on web page (on html or jsp).

i have already visited ***sshxcute,jssh,jtelnet*** many more like that..

But can't find any solution to start with.

Any Idea to drill in...??